# C++ find specific number in a string

Tags: c++, regex, string

I'm quite new to regular expressions. I have this string.

`string s = media_type=video|key_frame=1|pkt_pts=1516999|pkt_pts_time=50.566633|pkt_dts=1516999|`

I need to get 50.566633 value extracted using string operators and regular expressions in C++. Can some one suggest a way to do this?

Comment: https://www.myregextester.com/

Comment: `pkt_pts_time\=([\\+\\-]?(?:\\d*\\.?\\d+))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is well worth studying because it is so useful.

This works for me:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

std::string s = "media_type=video|key_frame=1|pkt_pts=1516999|pkt_pts_time=50.566633|pkt_dts=1516999|";

int main()
{
    // parens () define a capture group to extract your value
    // so the important part here is ([^|]*)
    // - capture any number of anything that is not a |
    std::regex rx("pkt_pts_time=([^|]*)");

    std::smatch m;
    if(std::regex_search(s, m, r))
        std::cout << m.str(1); // first captured group
}
```

**Click on [Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/rP6cU3/1)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But it says R is undefined.

Comment: @Asankasanjaya You must be using C++11 for regex to work. Did you compile using `-std=c++11` flag? (or VC++ equivalent). (in this instance raw string lits don't help so I removed it)

Comment: I got the code from you and made some changes. Now its working. These are the changes I did.

Comment: I changed the line regex rx("pkt_pts_time=([^|]*)"); to regex r("pkt_pts_time\=([\\+\\-]?(?:\\d*\\.?\\d+))");

Comment: I you can change it I can mark this as correct answer. Thank you for the help.